# how create a Controller partial class to override OnAuthorization?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, class, controller, partial

I'm trying to change the method `OnAuthorization`, so that it is available for any application ... this way:

```
public partial class Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ((string)(filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]) == "test")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }

}
```

but is showing the compilation error:

> Controller.OnAuthorization(System.Web.Mvc.AuthorizationContext)': no
>   suitable method found to override

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1):

You have to create you own base controller class:

```
public partial class BaseController : Controller
{
    protected override void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if ((string)(filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]) == "test")
        {
            filterContext.Result = new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
        }
    }
}
```

Use BaseController in your code.

And remember that `filterContext.RouteData.Values["action"]` can be `Test` or `TEST` or `tEST`.